# How to build hddimg for i.mx7

Tags: yocto

I have an i.mx7 som. I want to build a Yocto image which I can dd onto a usb stick to boot from. I believe that I want an hddimg image but cannot see how to create one (I have sdimg which works prefectly).

I would appreciate advice.

I have set IMAGE_FSTYPES to "hddimg" but get "ERROR: Nothing PROVIDES 'syslinux'"

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, the .sdimg will do the job perfectly.

Actually, it doesn't matter if the target storage is a SD-card, a USB flash drive or a real HDD as long as your bootloader is able to adress it (which is, obviously, the case of your board).

Simply dump your .sdimg to your usb flashdrive (`dd if=<.sdimg path> of=<sdcard device node, aka /dev/sdX>`) and it should work out of the box.

Nevertheless, just to explain a bit the error you met, it looks like `hddimg` is an image that include a bootloader (`syslinux` is a bootloader...) ... i guess that `hddimg` IMAGE_FSTYPES, since it requires syslinux, is for PC only, not for embedded computer.

Try burning the `.sdimg` to the flash drive and tell us if it works (or not) :-)